# How to run the query from a file in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I run a mysql query (just he query part) which is written to a file, eg. accounts.txt

```
/test/mysql -h testdb.com -P 8995 -p -u testaccount -e 
"select distinct
    amp.account_id
from
    account_marketplace_groups amp;" -D company > /tmp/output.csv
```

How can I put the actual query in a file and execute the above and still get the output in a csv

Would this be the right way to do it ?

```
/test/mysql -h testdb.com -P 8995 -p -u testaccount -e /account.txt  -D company > /tmp/output.csv
```

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-e` option can't be used with a filename, it expects the parameter to be the query. Just use input redirection, since `mysql` reads from standard input.

```
/test/mysql -h testdb.com -P 8995 -p -u testaccount  -D company < /account.txt > /tmp/output.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

+1 to Barmar's answer but here is another solution, which works equally well:

```
/test/mysql -h testdb.com -P 8995 -p -u testaccount \
  -e "source /account.txt"  -D company > /tmp/output.csv
```

That is, if you don't want to use `<` for input redirection, you can use the `-e "source ..."` command to read the file from within the command-line.